# LINQ to SharePoint and SPUserToken

Tags: security, linq

When creating a new Linq to SharePoint context, normally we don't pass a site object but we provide a request url.

So what should I do if I want to execute Linq queries under a different user context? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Please provide code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my own question. It is possible with switching HttpContext objects.

Here are the steps:

- Retrieve the user token from SPContext.Current
- Set HttpContext.Current to null
- Create a new SPSite with the user token
- Create a new Linq to SharePoint context

This way the new context is created within the context of the prefererred user.

I can provide code if someone needs it.

Comment: can you provide some code how you do that?  That'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPUserToken token = oWeb.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"].UserToken;
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(oWeb.Site.ID, token))
 {
    using (SPWeb elevatedweb = site.OpenWeb())
     {
      // Perform administrative actions       
     }
 }
```

You can also use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block for the same.

For in-depth information on the impersonation techniques, Check this out :

[Impersonation in SharePoint : An Extreme Overview](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/)